# Django - render to string fails to load CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I am trying to use Django(1.8) render_to_string to convert html to pdf with management command instead of using View/request. The following code is able to convert the template to pdf. But it fails to load CSS into the template.

```
def html_to_pdf():
    ...
    context = {'some_key': 'some_value'}
    html = render_to_string('my_app/sample.html', context)
    file.write(html)
    ...
```

sample.html

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'my_app/css/sample.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Also I have static defined in the setting file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my Django project, there is another View function which is able to load the template with CSS when the url get called. So I believe the issue has something to do with render_to_string.

Anyone can help it out?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?   I've got the same problem.  Thanks  Chris.

Comment: Did any of you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `django.core.context_processors.static` for Django<1.10 or `django.template.context_processors.static` for 1.10 in your template context processors, the problem is you are passing a simple context dictionary in, whereas with `render` in a view you magically get a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) which automatically populates a handful of variables based on what context processors you have in your settings. In this case the [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django-template-context-processors-static) populates a variable called `STATIC_URL` equal to the value of the same variable in your settings.

Comment: I am using 1.8 and have context_processors.static in my setting. Is it possible to manually add static_url in the context dictionary?

Comment: just tried to add: context['STATIC_URL'] = '/static/', but still didn't work

Answer (score -1):

you could try:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template


html = get_template("my_app/sample.html")
context = {'some_key': 'some_value'}
html_content = html.render(context)
file.write(html_content)
```